# 'No component factory found for [custom component]' in Angular|Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 with lazy-loaded pages. When trying to present a modal within a component within the page I get the following error:

```
No component factory found for CourseEditorComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

As you can see down below, I've added the CourseEditorComponent as entryComponent to *courses.modules.ts*, which gets imported by *dashboard.modules.ts*.

Am I getting something wrong about the way custom entryComponents are used in Angular/Ionic?

**Hierarchy**

```
DashboardPage
-CoursesComponent
--CourseEditorComponent
--CourseCreatorComponent
-InstructorsComponent
```

**Modules**

*dashboard.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DashboardPage } from './dashboard';
import { CoursesModule } from "./courses/courses.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(DashboardPage),
    CoursesModule
  ],
})
export class DashboardPageModule {}
```

*course.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses';
import { CourseEditorComponent } from "./course-editor/course-editor";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CoursesComponent],
  imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(DashboardPage)],
  entryComponents: [CourseEditorComponent],
  exports: [CoursesComponent,CourseEditorComponent]
})
export class CoursesModule {}
```

**CourseComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CourseEditorComponent } from "./course-editor/course-editor";

@Component({
  selector: 'courses',
  templateUrl: 'courses.html',
})
export class CoursesComponent {
  editCourse(data) {
    let editor = this.modal.create(CourseEditorComponent,{course: data});
    editor.present();
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to add the entry component to the main app module

Comment: @RahulSingh Yeah obviously, but isn’t there a smoother way? I assumed that I didn’t need to touch app.module.ts when taking advantage of lazy-loading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  entryComponents: [your modal component] // you need to add it to entry component
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As of now there is no support for the same there is a issue reported for the same in the Angular git repo [**LINK**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14324)

**Using an `EntryComponentsModule`**

Import `EntryComponentsModule` (where you define all entryComponents) to `AppModule` until the issue is fixed.

**Using `CourseEditorComponent` as page**

Turn `CourseEditorComponent` into a page and change `modal.create(CourseEditorComponent)` to `modal.create('CourseEditorComponent')`

Comment: Way to go. I've added a EntryComponentsModle to 'app/' and imported it to 'app.module.ts' so I can keep the AppModule clean and quickly fix it ASA this issue is fixed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just found a smoother solution:
Define CourseEditorComponent as a page and replace `CourseEditorComponent` with `'CourseEditorPage'` when creating a modal

Answer (score 3):

you have to add it under declarations[] and entryComponents